# Not fully understanding this part of code

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, unions

I recently came accross this code and I can't get my head around it. Could someone, please, explain me what is happening there?

```
union Color32
{
   struct ARGB
   {
      uint8_t b;
      uint8_t g;
      uint8_t r;
      uint8_t a;
   } parts;
   uint32_t argb;
   Color32() : argb(0) {}
   Color32(uint32_t c_argb) : argb(c_argb) {}
   Color32(uint8_t a, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
   {
       parts.a=a;
       parts.r=r;
       parts.g=g;
       parts.b=b;
   }
};
```

Comment: What can you make of it so far?

Comment: From the constructors in the `union`, I think this might be C++, not C.

Comment: Reading material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346536/difference-between-a-structure-and-a-union-in-c, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B.

Comment: Nice to know that unions have constructors. It is c++

Comment: My fault. It's c++ indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members of a `union` share storage. This is in contrast to a `struct` where each member is allocated distinct storage.

The effect of this code is that the members `b`,`g`,`r` & `a` of the `ARGB` struct share storage with the other member `argb` of the `Color32` `union`.

So the constructor that sets the value of `argb` implicitly sets the values of `b`,`g`,`r` & `a` as the ordered parts of the bit pattern of `argb`.

Conversely the `b`,`g`,`r` & `a` constructor builds up the value of `argb`.

The diagram under 'ARGB' here is a really good picture of how those parts are 'packed' into a 32 bit block.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

I probably don't need to explain that `b` stands for blue, `g`green , `r` for red and `a` for alpha (AKA Transparency)!

You may encounter difficulties if there is a requirement for big-endian /little-endian portability.

Answer (score 0):

ARGB is a structure of 4 uints which represents green, blue, red and for a I don't know. 
The structure is created with the name parts so when you have to use it you must act like: parts.r = 20 or parts.g = 50.

Then it create an object color which can contain the 4 parameters of the argb (4*8 = 32).

And it initialized the object color 32 with the 4 parameters that you give him : a,b,c,d

```
Color32(uint8_t a, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
   {
   parts.a=a;
   parts.r=r;
   parts.g=g;
   parts.b=b;
   }
```

To resume, you have an object named Color of 32 bits which contains 4 objects of 8 bits from the structure parts.