# Understanding data structure in usbjoy library from v-usb project

Tags: c, embedded, avr

good day to you all.

I am trying to make my own joystick, so I have been looking for references and then I found usbjoy project from v-usb wiki page (http://vusb.wikidot.com/project:usbjoy).

Then, I found data structure for buttons, taken from common.h in zip file from the website.

```
typedef struct
{
  uchar x; //Byte-0, ﾕ (0...255)
  uchar y; //Byte-1, Y (0...255)
        uchar z; //Byte-2, Handle-1 (0...255)
  uchar p; //Byte-3, Handle-2 (0...255)

  union {
    uchar buttons; //Byte-4, buttons 8
    struct
    {
      uchar btn1:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn2:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn3:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn4:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn5:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn6:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn7:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn8:    1; //0, 1
    } b;
  } u;
        union {
    uchar but; //Byte-5, buttons 4
    struct
    {
      uchar btn9:    1; //0, 1
      uchar btn10:   1; //0, 1
      uchar btn11:   1; //0, 1
      uchar btn12:   1; //0, 1
      uchar padding: 4; //Not use
                } b;
  } w;
} t_PsxController;
```

I understand that x and y are for left analog pad, z and p are for right analog pad, and u and w are for buttons. My questions are:

1. Why are u and w declared as unions?
2. Will the struct inside the unions ever be used?
3. What is the size of t_PsxController?
4. And finally, what do colons in `uchar btn1: 1;` and codes below it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t_PsxController` is a struct 6 bytes in size. Each byte is numbered in the comments of the code you posted. The colon `:` in some of the lines directs the compiler to devote a certain number of bits (1 or 4 in this example) to the item, rather than an entire byte. This makes each of the unions only 1 byte long.

```
t_PsxController controller;
```

will declare a struct called `controller` that you can use later. It is 6 bytes long.

To access members of the struct, use the `.` dot operator. The identifier you use will determine which member of the union you are accessing. E.g.,

```
controller.x = 23; // assigns a value to the byte 0
controller.u.b.btn1 = 1; // assigns a 1 to the first bit of the byte 4
uchar x = controller.u.buttons; // assigns 128 to x
```

You may want to use a pointer to `controller` at some point, especially when passing into a function. You then need to use the `->` operator as well as the `.` dot.

```
t_PsxController *ctlr = controller;

ctlr->u.b.btn2 = 1; // Now ctlr->u.buttons is 192
```

Comment: Are you sure btn1 start from MSB? Doesn't it start from LSB? I just found this post, it states otherwise. http://www.keil.com/forum/11158/the-bit-struct-in-union/

Comment: @swdmnd No, I'm not sure which way it goes. The direction depends on the compiler, but the link you give is for ARM, not AVR. I just wanted to show you how to reference the same byte in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are u and w declared as unions?

You will be using one button from eight button at a time right ? Only one member of data structure need to be accessed so union is used .Understand the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346536/difference-between-a-structure-and-a-union-in-c) between structure and union. Joystick can be utilized left pad ,right pad and

> Will the struct inside the unions ever be used?

Yes it represent different button so it will be used.

> What is the size of t_PsxController?

`t_PsxController` is structure and maximum size of structure is summation of all member of structure.

> And finally, what do colons in uchar btn1: 1; and codes below it mean?

Inside structure of union `uchar btn1: 1` represents unsigned char bit field that occupies 1 bits

Inside structure of union `uchar padding: 4` represents unsigned char bit field that occupies 4 bits