# How union data storing works. Getting confusing output

Tags: c, union

I could not understand how Union is printing data.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 union Values{
  int a;
  char b;
  int c;
 };
union Values val;
val.a = 1;
val.b= 2 ;
val.c = 300;
printf("%d,%d,%d",val.a,val.b,val.c);
return 0;
}
```

I getting output to 300,44,300

Comment: An `union` can't hold all three of those at the same time. If you want to store all of those things, did you intend to make a `struct` instead? Change the two `union` in your code to `struct` and see if you like that result better.

Comment: Me thinks you need to read this, possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346536/difference-between-a-structure-and-a-union

Comment: It's not clear what you're confused about.  Did you expect `val.a`, `val.b`, and `val.c` to all retain their values?  That's pretty much the opposite of what a union is for.  If you want  `val.a`, `val.b`, and `val.c` to all retain their values, what you want is a `struct`.  The whole point of a union is that it's just big enough to hold *one* of the values; they all overlap each other in memory.  The only value you can fetch from a union is the last value you stored in it.  Whenever you store a new value in a union, it overwrites all or part of all the others.

Comment: A union between an `int` and an `int` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Values` is union type of size `int`, which is maximum size of its members.

Considering the size of `int` is 4 bytes, then.

```
                   +------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
union Values val = |  1st byte  | 2nd byte    | 3rd byte    |  4th byte   |
                   +------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

When you store

```
val.c = 300; //binary 0b100101100
```

`val` will become

```
        +------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
  val = | 0010 1100  | 0000 0001   |             |             |
        +------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

When you access `val.b` you will read the only one byte which contains `0010 1100`.
And decimal equivalent of `0010 1100` is `44`.

Comment: In order to answer this, you must take endianess in account. You seem to assume big endian, but the OP is using little endian.

Comment: @Lundin Updated after your suggestion! Thank you.

Comment: "which is maximum size of its members." -->perhaps more. `union Values{
  double a;
  char b[9];
 };` still may need alignment padding.

Comment: @chux I would like to cover that too, but it will be too board for this answer which cover specific doubt of OP.