# Runtime error when printing string using union. It doesn't print string value but does print integer value

Tags: c, runtime-error, unions

the print statement[the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L80Ta.png)

```
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) //printing
    {printf("Name: %s\nAddress: %s\nOccupation: %s\nAge: %d", p[i].name, p[i].add, p[i].occ, p[i].age);}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also [please do not post images of text (the output in this case) because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Texts should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: You may want to use a structure instead of a union.

Comment: Try putting string values after assigning the integer value.

Comment: Learn what is union. [c - Difference between a Structure and a Union - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346536/difference-between-a-structure-and-a-union)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `p[i]` is a union, then it can hold only *one* of its members. However, in your print:

```
printf("Name: %s\nAddress: %s\nOccupation: %s\nAge: %d", p[i].name, p[i].add, p[i].occ, p[i].age);
```

you seem to think it holds *all* of the values. For that you don't need a `union` but a `struct`.