# Combine and unite the sequence of bytes in union

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, byte, unions

I am trying to combine and unite the sequence of bytes from an int and a short

when debugging and reading the memory it's aligned like this `[FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00]`

shouldn't it looked like this `[FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00]`  since i am using union?

```c
   union uniteByte{
        
        unsigned int blockOne;
        unsigned short blockTwo;
    };
    
    union uniteByte testing;
    
    testing.blockOne =0xffffffff; //4294967295
    testing.blockTwo = 0xffff; //65535
    

    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(testing)); // size is 4 why? shouldn't it be 6?
    printf("%u\n",testing.blockOne); // 4294967295
    printf("%u\n",testing.blockTwo); // 65535
    printf("%p",&testing); //0x7ffeefbff4e0 [FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00]
    printf("%p",&testing.blockOne); //0x7ffeefbff4e0 <-- the address is the same as in blockTwo
    printf("%p",&testing.blockTwo); //0x7ffeefbff4e0 <-- the address is the same as in blockOne
```

Comment: You're getting UB because `%x` expects an unsigned int, not an address. Addresses must be printed with `%p`. Besides `unsigned short` must be printed with `%d` because it'll be promoted to int, unless `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)`

Comment: Reading a different union member than the last one you wrote is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @ phuclv alright gona make that change thanks

Comment: @Barmar Type-punning via a union is fine in **C**, IIRC. It's UB in C++.

Comment: @AdrianMole I said implementation-dependent, not UB.

Comment: The result will depend on things like endianness.

Comment: @dn70a Not sure you are seeing the point of a union: the two members occupy the same memory, so why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: @AdrianMole When i read the memory it looks like `[FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00]` <--
whouldn't it be `[FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00]`
also when printing the sizeof(testing) it showing to be 4 bytes instead of 6

Comment: Change your `union` to a `struct` to see the behaviour you seem to be expecting. Maybe this will help: [Difference between a Structure and a Union](https://stackoverflow.com/q/346536/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole the problem with the struct is that it uses empty bytes to align as for a integer alignment location.  so if we reverse the position of blockOne and and blockTwo it would look like this `[FF FF 00 00 FF FF FF FF]`

Comment: Why are you printing 8 bytes of memory when the union only uses 4 bytes?

Comment: You might be able to get what you want using a packed structure.

Comment: @Barmar i should accept your comment as an answer `__attribute__((packed))`  changing union to packed structure did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a `union` is to use overlapping memory for each member, so the size is the size of the largest member, plus padding if necessary.

If you want the members to be independent, you have to use a `struct`. To get rid of the padding between members and at the end, use `__attribute__((packed))`.

Note that this will often have performance implications. CPU operations for moving numbers between memory and registers generally have alignment requirements, which is why structures normally have padding. When you pack the structure, the data has to be moved byte-by-byte instead of using single instructions for the full size of the number. So it should only be done when memory efficiency is at a premium and you need this time-space tradeoff.